# golang and excelize 2.8.0 with excel 2019 files

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I've been using the excelize library to basically take spreadsheets and amend the values of certain cells and then read the outputted formula values in another cell and it has been working perfectly. I now have a newer excel file from excel 2019 and its using XLOOKUP and MINIFS etc and now the output is not working as I would assume it is a newer engine? IS there a solution for this or is there some other library?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that such a problem has not happend to me and  the problem is probably related to the functions or parts of your code please send a sample of the code or functions you used in the code so that we can understand where the problem is

Comment: The issue is certain formulas. For example IF($D$6="City";XLOOKUP($D$10;Tables::Table 1::B7:B14;Tables::Table 1::C7:C14;0;−1;−1);IF($D$6="Higher Education";XLOOKUP($D$10;Tables::Table 1::E7:E14;Tables::Table 1::F7:F14;0;−1;−1);XLOOKUP($D$10;Tables::Table 1::H7:H14;Tables::Table 1::I7:I14;0;−1;−1)))